# How to install .exe file on windows embedded compact 7?

Tags: windows, embedded, windows-embedded-compact

I want to install a `.exe` file in a windows embedded compact 7 terminal. However when I click the file, nothing happens.

Hope someone can help, I am new to windows embedded compact 7.

Comment: What is the file? Does it actually need installing or is it a standalone app that does something hidden?

Comment: i want to install passmark bitpro.exe to be use to perform tests such as audio, CPU, etc.

Comment: Is it a command line app? Have you tried running it on full fat Windows 7 rather than embedded?

Comment: yes, it works in windows 7 but i need to have it install in embedded for testing purposes.

Comment: Ok, I have only have limited experience in embedded, but from what I have seen you usually need admin rights to do much with it, try logging on as admin and running the installer.

Comment: Tried it already but still nothing happens. I've searched the net but i can't find related topics for this. ^_^

Comment: :) Ok, I'm really not sure then, just hope an embedded guru sees this question! Or maybe someone on [superuser](http://superuser.com) will know.

Comment: Are you developing using the Windows Embedded SDK and on a development system that is intended for Windows 7 embedded development, or are you simply trying to load an app onto the Windows Embedded System that is already deployed?

Comment: I'm trying to load an app to windows embedded system that is already deployed.

Answer (score 0):

if it is truly an Embedded Compact device, then you're probably out of luck. The app you're talking about is a full Windows application. Windows Embedded Compact won't run it. WEC7 is more closely related to the old Windows Mobile Handhelds than Windows 7.

Are you sure it's Embedded Compact and not Embedded Standard?